# In yarn.lock, what is the meaning of separating package names with a comma?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Check out this `yarn.lock` [file example](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/):

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1
package-1@^1.0.0:
  version "1.0.3"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/package-1/-/package-1-1.0.3.tgz#a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3n4o5p6q7r8s9t0"
package-2@^2.0.0:
  version "2.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/package-2/-/package-2-2.0.1.tgz#a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3n4o5p6q7r8s9t0"
  dependencies:
    package-4 "^4.0.0"
package-3@^3.0.0:
  version "3.1.9"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/package-3/-/package-3-3.1.9.tgz#a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3n4o5p6q7r8s9t0"
  dependencies:
    package-4 "^4.5.0"
package-4@^4.0.0, package-4@^4.5.0:
  version "4.6.3"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/package-4/-/package-4-2.6.3.tgz#a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3n4o5p6q7r8s9t0"
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what the `package-4@^4.0.0, package-4@^4.5.0:` part  means. At first, I thought the comma acted as an OR condition, but in this case, just saying `package-4@^4.0.0:` would be enough. I searched all around, and I didn't find any detailed explanation about the `yarn.lock` file format.